# Correct way to handle abstract entities with JPARepositories?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a bunch of tables with exactly same columns, let's say, ID, NAME, DESCRIPTION. For legacy reasons I cannot change these tables.

In my models, I created an abstract super class for these, using the @MappedSuperclass annotation. I then created a repository for it:

```
JpaRepository<MyAbstractEntity, Long>
```

But this doesn't seem to work with JPARepository (or rather Hibernate?) as it's not a real entity.

So what is the preferred way to deal with such a hierarchy?

Comment: What exactly is "doesn't seem to work"?

Comment: With "@MappedSuperclass" this "doesn't work", but fails with Not a managed type error. However, using "@Entity" and "@Inheritance" for the base class it does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are using Hibernate as your persistence provider? It had [a bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6896), not returning the relevant JPA meta-model types when being asked for mapped superclasses. This was fixed in Hibernate 4.1.6, so upgrading to that version should solve the issue.

Comment: I am using Hibernate (should have mentioned it clearly in the original post) - version 4.1.9 - I swear I saw that error just before posting though,strange. Is there any difference if you use "@Mappedsuperclass" or "@Entity" and "@Inheritance"?

Comment: We essentially try to look up the id property using the domain type you declare at the repository. We do so using the JPA meta-model API, so assuming your provider correctly exposes that through `Metamodel.managedType(…)` we're fine. Does that mean it's working for you now?

Comment: Yes, now that I tried "@Mappedsuperclass" again, it works fine. The generated table structure looks the same as with the other method, but with "@Mappedsuperclass" I can also use "GenerationType.IDENTITY" for the ID, which is great, because it works better with my DBUnit tests. With "@Entity" and "@Inheritance" I had to switch to GenerationType.TABLE, which was hard to test with DBUnit as the generated IDs kept changing.

Comment: Awesome, great to hear! :)

Answer (score 1):

The thing is that how the `repository` can know which table to query based solely on the abstract class ? 
For me the best way is to create the repository you need based on your concrete classes.

Comment: Well, I did forget that. BUT: actually it looks like it uses the return type to determine the table, so you can have a repository for the base class and query methods returning sub classes and it looks like it works.